# Java ArrayList.contains() & add() method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, addition, contains

So I'm having this problem with adding an element to an ArrayList

I have a class `Media` with 3 fields and another class `Mediatheque` with 1 field(which is an ArrayList).

Let's say I have:

- A `Mediatheque media = new Mediatheque`
- An `equals(Media m)` method in class `Media` < (important method)

I need to write a method `add(Media m)` which:

- If the `media.contenu` does contain an element `equals` to the `Media m` I want to add, I must NOT add it and increase the `nbEx` field of the element contained in `media.contenu`

-Else I can add it using the `add` method provided by the `ArrayList` ( This doesn't seem too hard)

So I tried to write a `contains(Media)` method which uses the `equals(Media m)` method I wrote for the `Media` class and then use the `contains` method in the `add` method.

My question is that how am I supposed to write the `add` method? < (The Question)

I must write this using `ArrayList`, it is a school assignment
Sorry about the long code and the bad English, I'm a complete noob.

Here is my `Media` class:

```
package Ex1;

public class Media {
    private final String support; // Format: Book, CD, DVD,etc...
    private final String titre; // Title
    private int nbEx; // Number of copy

    public Media(String titre, String support){
        this.titre = titre;
        this.support = support;
        this.nbEx = 1;
    }

    public Media (){
        titre = "";
        support = "";
        nbEx = 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Media m){
        boolean equality = false;
            if (m instanceof Media){
                equality = (this.titre.equals(m.titre) && this.support.equals(m.support));
            }
        return equality;
    }

    public Media(Media m){
        this.titre = m.titre;
        this.support = m.support;
    }
}
```

And here is my `Mediatheque` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Mediatheque {
    ArrayList<Media> contenu;

    public Mediatheque(){
        this.contenu = new ArrayList<Media>();
    }

    public Mediatheque(Mediatheque m){
        this.contenu = m.contenu;
    }

    public boolean contains(Media m){
        int i = 0;
        boolean contain = this.contenu.get(i).equals(m);
        for(i = 0; i<this.contenu.size(); i++){
            if(contain)
                break;
        }
        return contain;
    }

    public int indexOf(Media m){
        boolean retVal = this.contenu.get(i).equals(m);
        for(Media i : contenu){
            if(contain)
                break;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void add(Media m){
        if(this.contains(m)){
            this.contenu.get(this.contenu.indexOf(m)).setNbEx(this.contenu.get(this.contenu.indexOf(m)).getNbEx()+m.getNbEx());
        }else{
            this.contenu.add(m);
        }
    }
```

My question is that how am I supposed to write the `add` method?

Sorry about the long code and the bad English, I'm a complete noob.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the restriction here? The title in the `Media` class, or do `support` and `nbEx` count as well?

Comment: Why did you reinvent the wheel for [`ArrayList#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: As you've implemented `equals` method, why not just use `ArrayList.contains`?

Comment: I think you should revise your datamodel. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have number of copies stored in the Media object(To my undersanding the instance of Media is a single item). It would be more clear(and faster) to use for example `Map<Media, Integer>`. And only increase the numbers in the Map. You're sort of creating a new collection-like data structure, but you should probably just reuse what JDK provides.

Comment: Were missing some information are you trying to implement a new data structure or are you just looking to organize the data?

Comment: your equals method should take an object as argument

Comment: Just another improvments: don't let package names start with an uppercase letter! Also if your `support` member only accepts types like `Book`, `CD` or `DVD` - why not using an enum instead?

Comment: I forgot to mention there are ready-made collection implementing exactly this functionality like Multiset or Bag from apache commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html
You just call `add(java.lang.Object object, int nCopies)` to increase number of "copies"

Comment: I cannot use the `ArrayList.contains` because I do not know how it evaluates my `Media` objects, or if it evaluates all my `Media` fields. I only need 2 fields `titre` and `support` of the objects to be evaluated in my `contains` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one overrides the `equals()` method, one is also supposed to override the `hashCode()` method. The `equals()` method takes an `Object` parameter. Here's how your `Media` class should look like:

```
// Media.java
public class Media
{
  private final String support;
  private final String title;

  public Media(String title, String support)
  {
    this.title = title;
    this.support = support;
  }

  public Media(Media media)
  {
    this(media.title, media.support);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return 31 * title.hashCode() + support.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object)
  {
    if (object instanceof Media)
    {
      Media media = (Media) object;

      return media.title.equals(title) &&
             media.support.equals(support);
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Then use a HashMap to map the media with its number of copies. Here's how that's done:

```
// MediaMap.java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MediaMap
{
  // Media to its Number of Copies mapping.
  private Map<Media, Integer> mediaMap;

  public MediaMap()
  {
    mediaMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void add(Media media)
  {
    mediaMap.put(media, mediaMap.getOrDefault(media, 0) + 1);
  }

  public void removeOneMedia(Media media)
  {
    if (mediaMap.containsKey(media))
    {
      mediaMap.put(media, mediaMap.get(media) - 1);
    }
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

Without overriding the `hashCode()` method in the Media class, the hash based collections won't work as expected.

You can also have a look at `MultiSet` data structure, and use that instead.

If you are to use `ArrayList` then here's how its done:

```
// Media.java
public class Media
{
  private final String support;
  private final String title;
  private int numberOfCopies;

  public Media(Media media)
  {
    this(media.title, media.support, media.numberOfCopies);
  }

  public Media(String title, String support, int numberOfCopies)
  {
    this.title = title;
    this.support = support;
    this.numberOfCopies = numberOfCopies;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return 31 * title.hashCode() + support.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object)
  {
    if (object instanceof Media)
    {
      Media media = (Media) object;

      return media.title.equals(title) &&
             media.support.equals(support);
    }

    return false;
  }

  public int getNumberOfCopies()
  {
    return numberOfCopies;
  }

  public void setNumberOfCopies(int numberOfCopies)
  {
    this.numberOfCopies = numberOfCopies;
  }
}
```

And here's a `MediaList` class which uses `ArrayList`:

```
// MediaList.java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MediaList
{
  private ArrayList<Media> mediaList;

  public MediaList()
  {
    mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void add(Media media)
  {
    set(media, +1);
  }

  public void remove(Media media)
  {
    set(media, -1);
  }

  private void set(Media media, int change)
  {
    if (change == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    int indexOfMedia = mediaList.indexOf(media);

    if (indexOfMedia != -1)
    {
      Media m = mediaList.get(indexOfMedia);
      m.setNumberOfCopies(m.getNumberOfCopies() + change);

      if (change < 0 && m.getNumberOfCopies() <= 0)
      {
        mediaList.remove(media);
      }
    }
    else if (change > 0)
    {
      mediaList.add(media);
    }
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, your Media class does look better indeed. But I am supposed to use the ArrayList because...well, school sucks.

Comment: @Heuksal: I have updated the answer. You can check it out to see how the particular code is written using `ArrayList`.

Comment: The problem is solved simply by overriding the `equals` method as you showed. Thank you for your attention sir.

Comment: @Heuksal: Cool. :) You can close this question by accepting any answer then.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @NeplatnyUdaj in the comment of your question, the use of a `Map` would greatly improve your code. Instead of recording the number of medias inside the Media object, use a `HashMap<Media, Integer>` to store your data in this way:

```
new HashMap<Media, Integer> map = new HashMap<Media,Integer>();

if ( map.containsKey(key) ) {
    map.put(key, (map.get(key) + 1));
} else {
    map.put(key, 1);
}
```

Where `key` is the media. (`m` in your code)

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your classes a little bit. I also implemented an add method. I assumed that you want to add media to the mediatheque if it is not already in the list. If it is in the list you want to add the nbex to the nbex that the item in the list has, right?
As the others I would advise you to use a HashMap() for counting if you don't need the number for your media objects.

Media.class

```
public class Media {
    private final String support; // Format: Book, CD, DVD,etc...    
    private final String titre; // Title    
    private int nbEx; // Number of copy

    public Media(String titre, String support){
        this.titre = titre;
        this.support = support;
        this.nbEx = 1;
    }

    public Media(Media m){
        this(m.titre, m.support);
    }

    public Media (){
        this("", "");
        nbEx = 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Media m){
            if (m instanceof Media){
                return (this.titre.equals(m.titre) && this.support.equals(m.support));
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Mediatheque.class

```
public class Mediatheque {
    ArrayList<Media> contenu;

    public Mediatheque(){
        this.contenu = new ArrayList<Media>();
    }

    public Mediatheque(Mediatheque m){
        this.contenu = m.contenu;
    }

    public boolean contains(Media m){
        for(Media media: this.contenu) {
            if(media.equals(m) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int indexOf(Media m){
        if(this.contenu.contains(m) {
            return this.contenu.indexOf(m);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void add(Media m){
        if(this.contains(m)) {
            Media media = this.contenu.get(this.contenu.indexOf(m));    
            media.setNbex(media.getNbex() + m.getNbex());
        } else {
            this.contenu.add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But the contains method you wrote doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why but I feel like it always return false.

Comment: Yeah, probably because the signature of the equals method is wrong: It is public boolean (Media media) {...} instead of public boolean(Object object) {...}. So it did not override the equals method that is inherited by Object and thus was never used. Thanks for remarking.